# How do I get through proxy server environments for non-standard services?

Tags: c++, c, windows, communication, wininet

I'm not real hip on exactly what role(s) today's proxy servers can play and I'm learning so go easy on me :-)  I have a client/server system I have written using a homegrown protocol and need to enhance the client side to negotiate its way out of a proxy environment.

I have an existing client and server system written in C and C++ for the speed and a small amount of MFC in the client to handle the user interface.  I have written both the server and client side of the system on Windows (the people I work for are mainly web developers using Windows everything - not a choice) sticking to Berkeley Sockets as it were via wsock32 for efficiency.  The clients connect to the server through a nonstandard port (even though using port 80 is an option to get out of some environments but the protocol that goes over it isn't HTTP).  The TCP connection(s) stay open for the duration of the clients participation in real time conferences.

Our customer base is expanding to all kinds of networked environments.  I have been able to solve a lot of problems by adding the ability to connect securely over port 443 and using secure sockets which allows the protocol to pass through a lot environments since the internal packets can't be sniffed.  But more and more of our customers are behind a proxy server environment and my direct connections don't make it through.  My old school understanding of proxy servers is that they act as a proxy for external HTML content over HTTP, possibly locally caching popular material for faster local access, and also allowing their IT staff to blacklist certain destination sites.  Customer are complaining that my software doesn't recognize and easily navigate its way through their proxy environments but I'm finding it difficult to decide what my "best fit" solution should be.  My software doesn't tear down the connection after each client request, and on top of that packets can come from either side at any time, basically your typical custom client/server system for a specific niche.

My first reaction is "why can't they just add my server's addresses to their white list" but if there is a programmatic way I can get through without requiring their IT staff to help it is politically better and arguably a better solution anyway.  Plus maybe I'm still not understanding the role and purpose of what proxy servers and environments have grown to be these days.

My first attempt at a solution was to use WinInet with its various proxy capabilities to establish a connection over port 80 to my non-standard protocol server (which knows enough to recognize and answer a simple HTTP-looking GET request and answer it with a simple HTTP response page to get around some environments that employ initial packet sniffing (DPI)).  I retrieved the actual SOCKET handle behind WinInet's HINTERNET request object and had hoped to use that in place of my software's existing SOCKET connection and hopefully not need to change much more on the client side.  It initially seemed to be my solution but on further inspection it seems that the OS gets first-chance at the received data on this socket since when I get notified of events via the standard select(...) statement on the socket and query the size of the data available via ioctlsocket the call succeeds but returns 0 bytes available, the reads don't work and it goes downhill from there.

Can someone tell me of a client-side library (commercial is fine) will let me get past these proxy server environments with as little user and IT staff help as possible?  From what I read it has grown past SOCKS and I figure someone has to have solved this problem before me.

Thanks for reading my long-winded question,

Ripred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your software can make an SSL connection on port 443, then you are 99% of the way there.

Typically HTTP proxies are set up to proxy SSL-on-443 (for the purposes of HTTPS).  You just need to teach your software to use the HTTP proxy.  Check the HTTP RFCs for the full details, but the Cliffs Notes version is:

- Connect to the HTTP proxy on the proxy port;
- Send to the proxy:

.

```
 CONNECT your.real.server:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n
 Host: your.real.server:443\r\n
 User-Agent: YourSoftware/1.234\r\n
 \r\n
```

- Then parse the proxy response, which will start with a HTTP status code, followed by HTTP headers, followed by a blank line.  You'll then be talking with your destination (if the status code indicated success, anyway), and can start talking SSL.

In many corporate environments you'll have to authenticate with the proxy - this is almost always HTTP Basic Authentication, which is pretty easy - again, see the RFCs.

Comment: Thanks I'll try what you mention but with port 80.  I mentioned being able to connect securely on 443 and then I just said port 80 so I want to clarify/refine my question a bit. The person I hired to implement the SSL solution used STunnel. They connect to it locally at 127.0.0.1:xx and it does the secure remote connection part.  I had hoped they would use the OpenSSL library but their solution worked so it was hard to argue for re-factoring it.

Knowing that, do I just need to take care of the proxy negotiation you recommend above and specify the remote address as 127.0.0.1:xx?

Comment: @Ripred: No, you can't tell the proxy to connect to `127.0.0.1` - that will just make it try and connect to itself.  You will need to do the proxy negotiation and then have `stunnel` start talking over the proxy connection after that, which it sounds like you'll have to do some refactoring to accomplish.  Bear in mind that many proxies will restrict the ports that you can use the `CONNECT` method with - potentially just to port 443.